# How can I iterate over specific index in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

So I have a list of index `close_index` I want to iterate over these specific index and update the column values.

```
hhinc8,owncar,longitude,latitude,category
5,1,-82.99194508,40.04649963,LRLC
6,2,-82.99584706,40.03738548,LRHC
5,1,-82.99697268,40.02674247,LRLC
6,2,-82.99160441,40.03612997,LRHC
1,2,-82.994716,40.04691778,ERHC
2,1,-82.99793728,40.04385713,ERLC
3,2,-82.98986012,40.03789279,ERHC
.
.
.
```

**close_index =[1,3,4]**

now in my code I update the all the close_index's `hhinc8` like
`df.loc[close_index,'hhinc8']=2`
now I want to update the category of all the close_index  by checking the `owncar` variable. If `owncar` is 1 category should be `LRLC` else it should be `LRHC`.

I thought the best way to do this is by looping over all the index in **close_index** and checking the `owncar` and updating the category.

But I am unable to figure out a way to **loop over specific index**.
As the dataset I have is very big, looping over the whole dataset is very inefficient.
If there is a better way to do this, Please let me know.

Comment: posted an answer on mapping the value to the category . You only want to update the close indexes?

Comment: yeah, only the close_index

Comment: i updated the solution to update only the close_index. Does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
# create a dictionary to map owncar to the category value
d={1: 'LRLC', 2: 'LRHC'}


close_index =[1,3,4]

df['category'] = df.loc[close_index]['owncar'].map(d)
df
```

or simply

```
hhinc8  owncar  longitude   latitude    category
0   5   1   -82.991945  40.046500   LRLC
1   6   2   -82.995847  40.037385   LRHC
2   5   1   -82.996973  40.026742   LRLC
3   6   2   -82.991604  40.036130   LRHC
4   1   2   -82.994716  40.046918   LRHC
5   2   1   -82.997937  40.043857   LRLC
6   3   2   -82.989860  40.037893   LRHC
```

to list the rows of close_index

```
df.loc[df.index.isin(close_index)]
```

```
    hhinc8  owncar  longitude   latitude    category
1        6       2  -82.995847  40.037385   LRHC
3        6       2  -82.991604  40.036130   LRHC
4        1       2  -82.994716  40.046918   ERHC
```

```
for i in close_index:
    print(df.iloc[df.index == i])
```

```
   hhinc8  owncar  longitude   latitude category
1       6       2 -82.995847  40.037385     LRHC
   hhinc8  owncar  longitude  latitude category
3       6       2 -82.991604  40.03613     LRHC
   hhinc8  owncar  longitude   latitude category
4       1       2 -82.994716  40.046918     ERHC
```

Comment: This works, but is there a way to iterate over just a list of index as well?

Comment: not quiet following you, but if I understand you correctly, you wanted this to be applied only on the list of the close_index. right? if so, then Yes, it is only applying to the indexes listed in close_index. My initial solution, didn't take that into account, but the current solution goes by the close_index. Check it out

Comment: Yeah this solutions works great, but I have another problem for which I need to loop over the close_index. I was asking is there a way to loop over just the close index?

Comment: is that what you're looking for ?   for i in close_index:
    df.iloc[df.index == i]['owncar'].map(d)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, so in the question close_index is [1,3,4] so I want to loop over only the index [1,3,4] something like ```for i in df[close_index]: print(i)``` which would give me rows 1,3,4.

Comment: updated the answer. check it out. hope it answers it. Sorry for taking longer to understand it :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, I didn't test though,

```
df[df["owncar"]==1].loc[close_index,'category']=LRLC
df[df["owncar"]!=1].loc[close_index,'category']=LRHC
```